# Failed to starting the server while installing SQL Workbench in Windows

Tags: server, mysql-workbench

I am installing SQL Workbench in Windows. While Starting the server, the app failed in this step. I have tried to set full access permission for the folder that points to the path. However, it still failed. The details have been attached below:
[image]
[image]

What can be the reasons here? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: OS error number 5 is *access denied*. You have a permissions issue where you're trying to install. Are you running the installer as an admin user? Where are you trying to install the database?

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, the place I am installing the database in is the E disk spack and I already set the full permission to execute it. However as I said in the post,  the issue has not been resolved

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I already used to fix this problem. I used the lastest JDK version. it worked for me.